# Erase newline at the beginning of a multline* environment

Tags: enumerate, alignment, multline

I have the following source:

```
    \item {\large  \begin{multline*} 
             \neg \left(\forall r_1,  r_2 \in \R \right)[\left(r_1 \cdot r_2 <0 \right)  \Leftrightarrow \\ 
        \left( \left( \left( r _ 1 < 0 \right) \land \left(r_ 2 < 0 \right) \right)  \lor  \left( \left( r _ 1 > 0 \right) \land \left( r_ 2 >  0 \right) \right) \right) ]\  \text{\pts{3}}
    \end{multline*} }  \vspace{-.4in}  \answerspacefullpage
```

Unfortunately, the distance between the list item's index and the produced multiline equation is a bit too much right now:

[image: Distance between list item and start of equation is too much.]

Any ideas about erasing that newline at the beginning of the equation?

Comment: Is your question about the linebreak after "(iv)", and how to avoid this break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `multlined` environment, from `mathtools`, with the relevant options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\vskip 3ex

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), start=4]
\item $ \begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth]
\neg \left(\forall r_1, r_2 \in \mathbf{R} \right)[\left(r_1 \cdot r_2 <0 \right) \Leftrightarrow \\
        \left( \left( \left( r _ 1 < 0 \right) \land \left(r_ 2 < 0 \right) \right) \right)\lor \left( \left( r _ 1 > 0 \right) \land \left( r_ 2 > 0 \right) \right) ]\qquad (\text{3 pts})
\end{multlined} $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs an `aligned` environment.

[image]

Observe that I've deleted all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives as they don't seem to be doing anything useful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),start=4]
\item \quad  
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    &\neg (\forall r_1, r_2 \in \R )
     (r_1 \cdot r_2 < 0 )  
    \Leftrightarrow \\ 
    &\qquad( ( ( r_1 < 0 ) 
     \land (r_2 < 0 ) )  
    \lor  
    ( ( r_1 > 0 ) 
     \land ( r_2 > 0 ) ) )
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```